# Linux Ubuntu 16.04.0 vs 16.04.3

Tags: kernel

I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of the two in terms of speed(reliability, stableness) and/or graphics performance(FPS). Linux 16.04.0 (4.4.0-21-generic)  or Linux 16.04.3 (4.10.0-28-generic).

My motherboard Driver/API is limited under Linux kernel 4.14.5, so Ubuntu 16.04 is my best choice. Please help me to choose between the two. Thank you.

Comment: When you install Ubuntu 16.04, and fully upgrade it - it'll become 16.04.6 (the current release).  So the end result is almost identical.  However the initial 16.04 LTS comes with the 4.4 kernel, where as releases after 16.04.2 have the HWE kernel enabled by default (4.10 is EOL and will be upgraded to 4.15) which is useful for later hardware, but in theory is less stable (has had less testing in production).  Excluding kernel, they'll both upgrade to 16.04.6  (You can enable HWE if you install with 16.04, then they'll be identical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu 16.04, and fully upgrade it - it'll become 16.04.6 (the current release). So the end result is almost identical (when compared with a 16.04.3 install fully-upgraded).

However a new 16.04 LTS install comes with the generic 4.4 kernel, where as new installs with releases after 16.04.2 have the HWE kernel enabled by default (4.10 is EOL and you'll find yourself upgraded to 4.15) is useful for later hardware, but in theory is *less stable* (has had less testing in production).

Excluding kernel, they'll both upgrade to 16.04.6 or result in the same packages installed.  You can also opt to enable HWE if you install with 16.04, then they will be identical.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for information about HWE kernels

Comment: can I use 16.04.6 with kernel 4.10? if the difference between 16.04.0 and 16.04.3 are only HWE, then meaning they almost identical? because I don't plan to do a hardware upgrade. My concern is about kernel stability because I'm planning to use it on my machine(embedded) running 8hrs-12hrs a day or might be 24/7.

Comment: 16.04.3 has later packages than 16.04 (besides kernel), but once upgraded all the packages will end up being 16.04.6.  Ubuntu releases of 16.04.2 and later have HWE enabled by default, but please note kernel 4.10 reached EOL on 13-Jan-2018 and has had no security updates since that time - it's a security risk if online.  If you install 16.04.3 with 4.10, the kernel will upgrade to a supported kernel (4.15)

Comment: I'm planning to use the default kernel(4.10) of 16.04.3. I will not update it and I will not use it online. So if I'm not using it to online even if 4.10 reached EOL, I think I can still use it. And I'm avoiding to use 4.15 because of my mobo limits under 4.14.5 only. So If I will choose between kernel 4.4 and 4.10, kernel 4.10 is more stable? am I right?

Comment: Nope - 4.4 is the more stable kernel.  It's older and thus had far longer being tested especially in production settings.  4.10 was a short term kernel (supported life was only 9 months in Ubuntu, or the life of Ubuntu 17.04).  I would opt for 4.4 or 4.15 due to 4.10's EOL status.  *The only reason to use 4.10 would be you can't use 4.15, and need something 4.10 has that 4.4 hasn't got, and back-porting it to 4.4 is not an option*

Comment: Thanks, I think I will choose 4.4 as you told that its more stable and better LTS than 4.10. Can you also give me some idea about the extension naming? 4.4.(0-21-generic)

Comment: 4.4 is the upstream kernel.  The -21 refers to the update level, -103 I believe is the current (all current patches are included).   Patches from later kernels are backported to 4.4 which cause the -21..103 to be incremented. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-image-4.4 .  The *generic* tells you it's the general purpose kernel (not low latency or one of the special-purpose options, for info see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to know more about Ubuntu. :)